# how to convert a viewstate value to a integer variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

i have the following code

```
private void ShowBill(int Prof_id,int Plan_id)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt = objmatportal.CreateBill(Prof_id, Plan_id);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblbillto.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CONT_FNAME"].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[0]["CONT_LNAME"].ToString() + "" + dt.Rows[0]["CONT_STATE"].ToString() + "" + dt.Rows[0]["CONT_CITY"].ToString();
        lblpayTo.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PAYTO"].ToString();
        lblDescription.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PLAN_NAME"].ToString();            
        lblAmount.Text ="Rs. "+string.Format("{0:0.00}",dt.Rows[0]["AMOUNT"]);
        lblTax.Text ="Rs. " +string.Format("{0:0.00}", dt.Rows[0]["VAT"]);
        LblTotal.Text ="Rs. "+ string.Format("{0:0.00}", dt.Rows[0]["TOTAL"]);
        ViewState["Total"] = dt.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Something gone wrong");
    }

}
```

on the above method 
on the line ViewState["Total"] = dt.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString(); 
i have assign the value to ViewState["Total"]

but when i run  the following method it shows the error "Specified cast is not valid." on following line

> Total = (int)(ViewState["Total"]);

```
public int TotalwithConvenience()
{
        int Total=0;
        decimal percentage = decimal.Parse(ViewState["CARD_PERCENT"].ToString());
        Total = (int)(ViewState["Total"]);
        decimal TDR = Total * percentage / 100;
        TDR = Math.Round(TDR);
        int tdrchrges = Convert.ToInt32(TDR.ToString());
        ViewState["convenience"] = tdrchrges;
        Total = Total + tdrchrges;
        return Total;

}
```

need help to how to solve this

Comment: What your viewstate says? what value its have

Comment: So where do you store the value in the `ViewState` and with which type? What happens if you also use `int.Parse` on total? `Total = int.Parse(ViewState["Total"].ToString());`

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit see the above code again i have edit the code

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
Total = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Total"]);
```

Comment: i have tried it but it  show the error

Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.Tointeger16(ViewState["convenience"]).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
ViewState["Total"] = dt.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString();
```

to store a value under "Total" in ViewState. This means you store a *string*.

When you use `(int)(ViewState["Total"])` you are telling the compiler that you stored an integer there, and so it fails at runtime (a string is not an integer).

Two possible solutions:

- as others mentioned, use `Total = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Total"]);` to read it
- use just `ViewState["Total"] = dt.Rows[0]["TOTAL"];` (without `.ToString()`) to store it (**if** that value really is an integer)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, but below statement resolved it

```
Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Total"]);
```